# Iterating a Javascript object with arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iterator

I have a javascript object as follows:

```
data = {
    'id': my_id,
    'report': my_report,
    'type': my_selection,
    'select': {
        'valid': {
            'table': {
                'pass': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                'fail': ['x', 'y', 'z']
             }
        },
        'invalid': {
            'table': {
                'pass': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                'fail': ['x', 'y', 'z']
            }
        }
     }
 };
```

I would like to use an iterator (double iterator?) to extract all the valid/invalid table pass/fail data.

So, I want to create an iterator that takes the arguments ('valid', 'invalid') and another with the arguments ('pass', 'fail').

I am using this snippet as an example for getting one of the iterators working:

```
function iterate() {
    let items = [];

    for (let iterator of arguments) {
        items.push(data.select[iterator]);
    }
    return items;
}

var selector_types = iterate('valid', 'invalid');
```

This returns the 'table' objects as expected:

```
0 {table: Object}
1 {table: Object}
```

But ideally the iterate() would take two sets of args, something like:

```
function iterate() {
    let items = [];

    for (let iterator of arguments) {
        items.push(data.select[iterator[0]].table[iterator[1]]);
    }
    return items;
}

var selector_types = iterate(['valid', 'invalid'], ['pass', 'fail']);
```

The idea of this is to get the pass/fail data for both the valid/invalid keys in one go. This (of course) doesn't work and returns undefined.

Is there an iterative solution to what I am attempting?

Regards,

MJ

Comment: @MJ, could you please let me know , what your end result should be?

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi, the data in question is in a localStorage var. I want to read that data in and extract all the relevant data from all the arrays, based on the selector (valid or invalid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some nested loops?

```
function iterate() {
    let items = [];

    for (let i of arguments[0]) {
        for (let j of arguments[1]) {
            items.push(data.select[i].table[j]);
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

You loop through the states `valid` and `invalid`, and for each one, you then loop through its `pass` and `fail` states, meaning you will loop through four states in total.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Toastrackenigma. I tried your solution and received the following: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.select[i]')

Comment: @MikeJames Hmm, strange, it works for me. Are your `data` object and the arguments you are passing in the same as the ones in your question? Here's a JSfiddle of it running: https://jsfiddle.net/n0z9oa2c/

Comment: basically yes. The data object I posted is structurally the same as the version of the data object I am using, but simplified by reducing the number of selectors and arrays, but is copied directly from my prototype that creates the object. I'll play around with it a bit and see what the issue is... Thx!